# Using datatypes according to OS Architecture

Tags: c++, c, types

I am revising all my concepts in C/C++. I started with datatypes and suddenly I came across one question, when to use which datatypes from the following?

We have `uint_64` `uint_32` and `uint_16`. Now for my clear understanding please tell me is that number (i.e. 64, 32, 16) meant for number of bits for a particular datatype and how they affected by OS architecture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. 64, 32, 16 stand for the number of bits used to store the uint. The OS architecture does not constrain you to use a specific type, but can influence the performance of the program.

The OS can influence the maximum amount of memory your process can use, because it gives you the virtual address length.

Also if you use a 32bit OS, then it will use only the 32bit registers in your CPU so the performance of using uint_64 will be lower. Using a 64bit OS will enable using the 64bit registers in the CPU and using uint_64 will fit in just one register.

Comment: Thanks. one more doubt. If we have long data type why I should use uint_64 for same bits?

Comment: Well, for getting 64bits you need to use "long long". However "long long" is a signed type (can hold negatives also). uint_64 is an unsigned and will keep only positive values. Check here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Answer (score 0):

Usually when developers encode number of bits in type name they emphasize that the type should have same size, no matter what kind of architecture is used.